# load data into Veriable UserForms & controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which running on a table in excel sheet (T_List). the code purpose is to load data from tabl to user forms controls. the user forms and controls are veriable. The code is stucking when it's on:
    UserForms(FormName).Show
and the error massage is "Type Mismatch":

```
Public Sub Load_Data_to_Form()
Dim T_Test As Integer
Dim CurrRaw As Integer
Dim CurrValue As String
Dim FormName As String
Dim Control_Yes As String
Dim Control_No As String

T_Test = Sheets("T_list").Range("T1").Value   'Total raws in excel table
CurrRaw = Sheets("T_list").Range("N7").Value   'current raw

For i = 1 To T_Test 'running on test parameter table
    CurrValue = Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(CurrRaw, i + 7).Value
    FormName = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 6).Value
    Control_Yes = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 4).Value
    Control_No = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 5).Value

If CurrValue = "Pass" Then
   UserForms(FormName).Show     '---> **the code stuck here**
   UserForms(FormName).Controls(Control_Yes) = True
   UserForms(FormName).Controls(Control_No) = False
ElseIf CurrValue = "Fail" Then
   UserForms(FormName).Show
   UserForms(FormName).Controls(Control_Yes) = False
   UserForms(FormName).Controls(Control_No) = True 
End If
Next
End Sub
```

What i'm doing wrong? how to call the veriable userform to be opened and saving the value into its controls?

Comment: Try substituting `UserForms(FormName).Show` to `FormName.Show` (without quotes).

Comment: But how? `FormName` is a string variable which is set to have the actual form name.

Comment: @AntiDrondert - it doesn't work, error massage is 'Invalid Qualifier'

Comment: Because you need to load forms before they will be avaible in `UserForms`

Comment: @AntiDrondert what should i need to change in my code in order it will work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me - for referencing MSForms.UserForm object.
but requires additional permissions.

> Excel Options > Trust Centre > Macro Settings > Trust access to the
>   VBA Project object model

below function return the userform object matching with input name.

```
Public Function UserForms(FormName As String)
    Dim c As Object
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If c.Type = 3 And c.Name = FormName Then
            Set UserForms = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

and modify your code as below :

```
Dim frm As Object
Set frm = UserForms(FormName)

If CurrValue = "Pass" Then
   frm.Show
   frm.Controls(Control_Yes) = True
   frm.Controls(Control_No) = False
ElseIf CurrValue = "Fail" Then
   frm.Show
   frm.Controls(Control_Yes) = False
   frm.Controls(Control_No) = True
End If
```

Comment: I can't enable the checkbox of "Trust access to the VBA Project object model" (it's blocked)

Answer (score 0):

UserForms.Add Method - without additional functions.

```
Dim frm As Object
Set frm = UserForms.Add(FormName)

If CurrValue = "Pass" Then
   frm.Show
   frm.Controls(Control_Yes) = True
   frm.Controls(Control_No) = False
ElseIf CurrValue = "Fail" Then
   frm.Show
   frm.Controls(Control_Yes) = False
   frm.Controls(Control_No) = True
End If
```

Comment: It's not working. it's stucking on  Set frm = UserForms.Add(FormName), error massage: 'Argument not optional'

Comment: If you're using this answer, remove the user function `UserForms`. Above error thrown because it is referring to the user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'Trust access to the VBA Project object model' option is blocked due to my organisation policy, and i can't use the UserForms(FormName) function as suggested below, i solved the problem by using array which save the userforms names.
Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Load_Data_to_Form()
Dim T_Test As Integer
Dim CurrRaw As Integer
Dim CurrValue As String
Dim FormName As String
Dim Control_Yes As String
Dim Control_No As String
Dim FormArray As Variant 'define array which hold userforms names
FormArray = Array(Test_Procedure1, Test_Procedure2, Test_Procedure3, Test_Procedure4)

T_Test = Sheets("T_list").Range("T1").Value   'Total raws in excel table
CurrRaw = Sheets("T_list").Range("N7").Value   'current raw

For i = 1 To T_Test 'running on test parameter table
    CurrValue = Sheets("Test_Data").Range("D_Start").Offset(CurrRaw, i + 7).Value
    FormName = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 6).Value
    Control_Yes = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 4).Value
    Control_No = Sheets("T_list").Range("T_Start").Offset(i, 5).Value

    For j = 0 To 3 'Running on 4 values in the FormArray
      If FormName = FormArray(j).Name Then

         If CurrValue = "Pass" Then
            FormArray(j).Controls(Control_Yes) = True
            FormArray(j).Controls(Control_No) = False
         ElseIf CurrValue = "Fail" Then
            FormArray(j).Controls(Control_Yes) = False
            FormArray(j).Controls(Control_No) = True 
         End If
       End If
     Next
Next
Test_Procedure1.Show '(show the first form and the for rest form the user can press on button 'next' in each form..)

End Sub
```